# CSS - Child Selector - nth-child(1) - interleaved - selecting just onces the first element

Tags: css, css-selectors

i do have a problem in selecting a HTML Element just once over CSS.

[code debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55oKh.png)

what i want to do is just selecting the marked tr - element in the table. the problem is, that the code do have more the one tables interleaved. which means that the child selector marks then every first tr - element in the hole table. but i just want to select explicit this first tr and nothing further more. is there a way to do this ? --> note : the #ID of the tr i could not use. i should use the classes which are marked and the element structure. would appreciate any help. best regards Marc

my current CSS looks like:

```
    .visible  .sapzencrosstab-Crosstab > tbody:first-of-type > tr:nth-of-type(1) 
 {  
      display: none !important;  
  }
```

[painting css selection red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M9dL.png)

Comment: `i just want to select explicit this first tr and nothing further more.` : this is your answer --> you have plenty of classes and iD

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hints i got currently the followed css- selector implemented:

```
  .visible  .sapzencrosstab-Crosstab > tbody:first-of-type > tr:nth-child(1)
```

i got a good result in painting the background red, but a bad result in let the table disappear, may there are other problems which will not relate to the css selection.